# Hand-Signs Recognition using Deep Learning Convolutional Neural Networks

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network

I am developing a CNN model to recognize 24 hand-signs of American Sign Language. I have 2500 Images/hand-sign. The data split is:
Training = 1250 Images/hand-sign
Validation = 625 Images/hand-sign
Testing = 625 Images/hand-sign

How should I proceed with training the model?:
1. Should I develop a model starting from fewer hand-signs (like 5) and then increase them gradually?
2. Should I start models from scratch or use transfer learning (VGG16 or other)
Applying data augmentation, I did some tests with VGG16 and added a dense classifier at the end and received these accuracies:
Train: 0.87610877
Validation: 0.8867307
Test: 0.96533334

[Accuracy and Loss Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lq11e.png)

Test parameters:
NUM_CLASSES = 5
EPOCHS = 50
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = 125
VALIDATION_STEPS = 75
TEST_STEPS = 75
Framework = Keras, Tensorflow
OPTIMIZER = adam

Model:

```
model = Sequential([
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH ,3)),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),

    Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),

    Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),

    Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),

    Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)),

    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),

    Dense(NUM_CLASSES, activation='softmax')
])
```

If I try images with slightly different background and predict the classes (predict_classes()), I do not get accurate results. Any suggestions on how to make the model robust?

Comment: Since you already have a big dataset, transfer learning isn't necessary IMO. Try to launch the training with 3 hand signs, and if the model score increases, add a new sign until either the accuracy decreases or you run out of signs to add. If you end up in the first case (accuracy drops out), you might want to move your question to a [dedicated stack exchange site](https://ai.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with 3 signs but the accuracy drops when I try for 5 signs. I have posted it in the dedicated stack exchange site.